# Make an app handleOpenURL only

Tags: ipad, url

I have an app that is part of a suite of related apps. It's job is to receive data from other apps and to do some very specific things with it. All works fine launching the app and passing data with handleOpenURL. But, I'd like to make the app ONLY launch when called from another app. That is, not tap-able on the home screen. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved: the launchOptions in appDidFinishLaunching contain the calling URL and calling app Bundle ID if the app was launched from another app. So I just check there. Thanx.

Comment: how is it not tappable from the home screen then?

Answer (score 0):

If not opened with a URL, display a dashboard showing the other apps that are installed, and force the user to start one of them. (check by using UIApplication canOpenURL)